# Error with Webpack and Angular Fullstack installing 3rd party npm modules

Tags: node.js, angular, dependency-injection, webpack, angular-fullstack

So I have been working with angular fullstack for a while now. I am having an issue with webpack at this point. I need to install an npm module called bb-rest which can be found [here][1].

This module is an extension of Blackboard Learns public API for Developers. When install the module into the project, and add it to the app.js file as I normally do other NPM modules, Webpack throws a fit. It is not able to find module 'fs' and from there more errors come up.

Item | Version
----- | -----
generator-angular-fullstack | 4.2.2
Node | 6.11.3
npm | 5.4.1
Operating System | OS X 10

Item | Answer
----- | -----
Transpiler | Babel 
Markup | HTML 
CSS | SCSS 
Router | ngRoute
Client Tests | Jasmine 
DB | SQL
Auth | Y

NPM MODULE: bb-rest

I have looked through many of the previous issues with the error 'Cannot resolve module 'fs'' and have done changes to the config variable in the webpack.make.js file from solutions such as these.

1. [Here](https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable/issues/9)
2. [This one as wel](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I)
3. [Tried this as well](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/8#issuecomment-55568520)
4. [Last Resort](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2605)

When I attempt to inject the dependency in the app.js file, webpack upon compiling throws a fit. I've tried the approaches in the links provided above in order to resolve this with no luck. I even tried simply importing the required dependency into my controller, or a specific file where I need it, and webpack goes crazy. I set up a test project with just a simple node/express webapp and that works fine. I'm not too familiar with webpack and it's inner workings so I was wondering if anyone had any similar issues when trying to use third party npm modules in the stack.

Console Error Produced by Webpack upon compiling: pastebin.com/26RmwEUZ

Comment: What does your current webpack.config.js look like right now?

Comment: There is no webpack.config.js. The way angular fullstack handles this is it defines a config variable in the webpack.make.js file, and sets all the configuration settings, and exports the variable during compile.

Comment: do you mean angular-cli?

Comment: No, this is the Angular Full stack https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack